# d3.js: highlight an x-axis label on a column/bar chart

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart

I've written a simplified column chart script in D3.js.

here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rolfsf/F36Vw/

The purpose is to compare a number of items smaller and larger than the item in focus.

like this:

[image]

**How can I select and highlight that $750k x-axis label, and how can I add that additional label identifying the focal item (Ace Widgets)?**

I'm looking for something more precise than aiming for the middle ;-)

My data currently looks like this (can easily be changed):

```
var data = {

    "sales": [
            [600, 1],
            [650, 2],
            [700, 3],
            [750, 2],
            [800, 1],
            [850, 2],
            [900, 3]
    ]
};
```

and the column script is here:

```
function miniColumnChart(){

    var barWidth = 20;
    var margin = {
        top: 64,
        right: 32,
        bottom: 64,
        left: 32,
        labels: 32
    };
    var height = 300; //overridden by width in call
    var width = 500; //overridden by width in call    
    var chartTitle = ["test"];
    var yAxisLabel = "y axis label";
    var xAxisLabel = "x axis label";
    var xformat = function(d){return d;};
    var focus;

    function chart(selection) {
        var maxBarHeight = height - (margin.top + margin.bottom);
        var chartWidth = width - margin.right - margin.left;

        d3.select('svg').remove();//remove old charts

        selection.each(function(data) {

            var xValue = function(d) { return d[0]; };
            var yValue = function(d) { return d[1]; };

            var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
                .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d[0]; }))
                .rangeRoundBands([margin.labels, chartWidth], 0);

            var y = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d[1]; })])
                .range([maxBarHeight, 0])
                .nice();

            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").tickFormat(xformat);

            //var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

            var svgContainer = d3.select(this).append("svg")
                .attr("class", "chart mini-column-chart")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height).append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

            svgContainer.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate( 0," + (height - margin.top - margin.bottom) + ")")
                .call(xAxis)

                .append("text")
                .attr("class", "axis-label")
                .attr("x", width/2)
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("dy", 48)
                .text(xAxisLabel);

            var header = svgContainer.append("text")
                .attr("class", "chart-title")
                .attr("x", width/2)
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("dy", -32)
                .text(chartTitle);

            var barValues = svgContainer.append("g")
                .attr("class", "bar-values");

            barValues.selectAll("text")
                .data(data)
                    .enter().append("text")
                .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                    return ((i+1) * x.rangeBand());
                })
                .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]);})
                .attr("dy", -5)
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .text(function(d) {return d[1];});

            svgContainer.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")//.call(yAxis)
                .append("text")
                .attr("class", "axis-label")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", 8)
                .attr("x", -(height-margin.top-margin.bottom))
                //.attr("dy", ".71em")
                .style("text-anchor", "start")
                .text(yAxisLabel);

            var bars = svgContainer.append("g")
                .attr("class", "bars");

            bars.selectAll(".bar")
                .data(data)
                    .enter().append("rect")
                .attr("class", "bar")
                .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                    return ((i+1) * x.rangeBand())-(barWidth/2);
                })
                .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]);})
                .attr("width", barWidth)
                .attr("height", function(d) {
                    return (maxBarHeight -y(d[1]));
                });
        });
    }


    chart.title = function(_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return chartTitle;
        chartTitle = _;
        return chart;
    };

    chart.x = function(_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return xValue;
        xValue = _;
        return chart;
    };

    chart.y = function(_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return yValue;
        yValue = _;
        return chart;
    };

    chart.width = function(_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return width;
        width = _;
        return chart;
    };

    chart.height = function(_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return height;
        height = _;
        return chart;
    };

    chart.barWidth = function(_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return barWidth;
        barWidth = _;
        return chart;
    };

    chart.xformat = function(_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return xformat;
        xformat = _;
        return chart;
    };

    chart.yAxisLabel = function(_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return yAxisLabel;
        yAxisLabel = _;
        return chart;
    };

    chart.xAxisLabel = function(_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return xAxisLabel;
        xAxisLabel = _;
        return chart;
    };

    return chart;
}

d3.select('#chart')
  .datum(data.sales)
  .call(miniColumnChart()
     .title("Similar Companies")
     .xformat(function(d){return '$' + d + 'K';})
     .yAxisLabel("# of Similar Companies")
     .xAxisLabel("Company Size")
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, store a reference to the `g` selector into which you're drawing your axis:

```
var xAxisG = svgContainer.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate( 0," + (height - margin.top - margin.bottom) + ")")
  .call(xAxis)
```

Then, you can select all the ticks inside it:

```
xAxisG.selectAll('.tick')
```

Ticks are the `g` elements containing `text` and `line`, which `d3.axis` creates for you. Then iterate over the ticks in this selection:

```
.each(function(d, i) {
    // In here, d is the ordinal value associated with each tick
    // and 'this' is the dom element
})
```

Inside the loop, you can "pick" the tick you're interested in updating and you can color its text, etc:

```
.each(function(d, i) {
    if(d == 750) {
        d3.select(this)
            .append('text')
            .text("Ace Widgets")
            .attr({
                "text-anchor": "middle",
                dy: 33,
                "font-size": ".8em"
            })
        d3.select(this)
            .selectAll('text')
                .style("fill", "red")
    }
```

Here's the [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meetamit/F36Vw/1/)

Comment: Something problematic that arises from this is that if you have this wrapped inside an update function for dynamic data, then the .append(text) part will continue adding text elements and not change what is already there.  Trying to figure out a solution here, will post if I do.

Comment: @Adam That implies that `xAxisG` is also being duplicated on each update, because `var xAxisG = svgContainer.append("g")` runs on each update. If so, you'd have to modify things to only create the axis once.

Comment: Is that necessarily true? You could have `var xAxisG = svgContainer.append("g")` outside of your update function if it's the case that the axis isn't change except for the text being manipulated in the `.each()` bit of the code.

Comment: @Adam Oops... yeah, you're correct. A sort of standard d3 way of preventing `.append('text')` from actually adding the text each time is to refine the preceding line to be `d3.select(this).selectAll('text').data([null]).enter().append('text')`. That way text is only created if it doesn't already exist. Probably would make sense in this case to give the `text` element a class (e.g. `attr('class', 'tick-label')`) and use that class in the query selector (e.g `d3.selectAll('text.tick-label')`

Comment: and the `.data([null])` is getting a 1-index array of null so that d3 looks to create (if it doesn't exist), or update only 1 element for the single index, right?

Comment: @Adam Correct: since the key function is not supplied (2nd param to `data()`), it defaults to `function(d,i) { return i; }`, which produces the desired results